# Bad colors in groovy in IDEA

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

[image: if statement and missing symbol dark]

the screenshot is of a gradle build file, the "black" text highlights as "cannot resolve symbol" I can't figure out where these colors are coming from, so that I can change them. This specific screenshot, it seems to affect most the dark themes I've tried. Where can I change these to be readable colors?

Comment: Look under `File > Settings... > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General` and change (probably) the "unknown symbol" color.

Comment: is not unknown symbol, that's apparently red

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing this worked for me:
`File > Settings > Colors & Fonts > Groovy > Unresolved reference access`